# Why HTML hyperlink is not working in my sub folder?

Tags: html, broken-links

I have created sub-folder **"Pages"** in my root directory and create "News.html" inside it .In this html file, i create hyperlink refer to root directory but when i click on  link Nothing Happens instead of opening index.html page.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


<title>web page</title>


</head>

<body>


<h1>This is News Page</h1>

<a href = "\index.html">Index</a>

</body>

</html>
```

I know alternatively this can work:

```
<a href = "../index.html">Index</a>   <!- ../ to target a parent folder
```

But why referring back to directory cannot work?

Comment: if you remove / from /indext.html  what happens?

Comment: "/index.html" instead of "\index.html", you can also type only "/" to point to root, it will find index.html automatically

Comment: when i remove / this , Browser says "File was not found".

Comment: I tried this / index.html but not working

Comment: write "/index.html" not "\index.html" even you are in windows.

Comment: I tried /index.html but  browser says file is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use just the code below to target a parent folder's file

```
<a href = "../index.html">Index</a>   <!- ../ to target a parent folder -->
```

> note : if you use live server from visual studio code that won't work
>   because of security problems and access limitation hope it helps !